# Bootstrap 3.3.7 modal 'shown' event fires intermittently

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

My Bootstrap modal dialog displays as intended every time I click to launch it, the problem is, the 'shown' event does not always fire.

Once the modal is displayed, a javascript function needs to be run to render a map inside one of the modals DIV's, but for this to be possible, the Modal (and thus its HTML) have to have been fully rendered in order that the Javascript can insert elements into the DOM.
To ensure that the modal has been fully rendered, the ***bs.modal.shown*** event is used.  This event fires only when the modal is fully constructed, so this event is used to call a function which loads the map.

It was apparent that this event was not always firing, as sometimes when the modal was launched the map was not rendered in the modal.  Putting a log to console on the bs.modal.shown event has shown that it is definitely the event which is not firing, and not a failure in the function which is called to render the map.

Using Chrome DevTools, there are no errors or warnings displaying when the shown event does not fire.

It may be interesting to note that this event fires 95% of the time on my dev machine when debugging, but only around 50% of the time when deployed to our IIS web server test environment.

My application is an ASP.Net MVC SPA, so my modal HTML is partly defined on my layout page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then a partial view is defined, which is injected into the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body padding-sm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("PV_flowModelDialog", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
```

Then in the Javascript on the modal I have

```
$('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      console.log("Modal container shown.")
      <....function calls here...>
})
```

I'm then using the 'hidden' event handler to confirm to log that the modal has been hidden (in addition to the fact the modal is visibly hidden).  This event fires consistently:

```
$('#modal-container').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log("hidden.bs.modal event.")
})
```

So the question is, what could be causing the shown event to only fire intermittently?  Any ideas on what could cause this or how to go about investigating this further or of a workaround to ensure this event (or equivalent) fires every time would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the modal is hidden to start:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-containerl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I've tried this but it makes no difference.  I've edited my question to include the fact that the 'hidden' event does fire every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've made a number of changes that appear to have resolved this issue:

1) Possibly a major omission from my original post was that at the end of my 'shown' event handler, I had this line: $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');  So in context:

```
$('#modal-container').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      console.log("Modal container shown.")
      <....function calls here...>

      $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');
})
```

2) I also found that whilst the Show and Shown handlers were within my Partial View (which was being injected into the BS modal dialog), they were not always firing.  I moved these out of the Partial View and into my MVC Layout.cshtml.  On doing this, the **events now fired every time without fail**.  So now this part of the Layout.cshtml is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('show.bs.modal');
    });

    var mapLoadCount = 0;

    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('shown.bs.modal');

        defineMapContent();
        loadmap();
        addInteractions();
    });
</script>
```

Occasionally the map does not load into the modal's div the first time the modal dialog is displayed.  However, the show and shown events are firing (this can be seen in the console log).  If this persists, I will see if adding a short delay between the event firing and the functions within the event being called, resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using partial views. I was loading the data and modal via a get through a button click; however it would only fire once. Reloading the modal/data never worked after the first attempt. The get function was on the parent, while the click event was on the child. I solved it by changing the button click event to a body click event and used the jQuery data attribute to store the url. Here's an example:

```
                 $('body').on('click', '.modal-edit', function (e) {
                    $.get($(this).data("target"), { "_": $.now() }, function (data) {

                    $('<div id="modal-container-edit" class="modal fade">' +
                        '<div class="modal-content" id= "modalbodyEdit" >' +
                        data + '</div></div>').modal();
                });
            });
```

my button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm modal-edit" data- 
     target="@Url.Action("Edit", "Bin", new { Id = m.id })">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed this issue for me was removing the "fade" class from the modal.

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

For whatever reason, that seems to interfere with the "shown" event firing consistently when in a MVC partial view.

If you still want the animation, overriding the default "fade" class with something like the following also worked for me.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal.fade.show .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```